# How do I search using an id , but use a slug in the url link in React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, slug

I am getting my posts in React using a fetch to my Rails API. In this information, I'm getting a primary key, and a slug (which I would like to use for the URL).

This is an example API call in Post.js

```
axios
    .get(`/api/posts/${params.postId}`
```

For example for a post id of 1 and a slug that is (this-is-a-slug).
I would like to be able to search using the id and have the URL be

/post/this-is-a-slug instead of post/1

This is the current route in Routes.js

```
      <Route path={"/post/:postId"} exact strict component={PostShow} />
```

I know using Primary Id's are faster than using strings to search, so it'd be nice if I could search with the id's but show the slugs in the title.

What do I need to do to get this to work? Do I need to create a slug model with a slug id, and then reference to the post id. I'm just a little confused. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Beware I don't know anything about `slug` :)  So, you are getting a response from backend and it has an `id` and a `slug` right? Then you can use it of course. `:postId` is just a name, it can be anything. What you pass to your `Link` component is matched with this parameter. That is all. If you pass `id` it will be `id`, if you pass `slug` it will be `slug`. Like <Link to=`/post/${slug}`... > If you can pick this and use in the component, then use it.

Comment: Where does the information come from about which id's are actually available for fetching?

Comment: I have a posts index page, which has the JSON information of all the posts, including the id.

Comment: Are you looking for the React router or the Rails router to match on your slug?  If the Rails router, you can precede your slug with the id, so in your case it would be "1-this-is-a-slug". Then in rails, you call to_i on the value when you get it. to_i will truncate the string after the first non numeric character, and you will be left with only the id.

Edit: it looks like Javascript's parseInt() has the same behavior.

Comment: just search with teh slug, the speed difference is likely negligible.

Comment: Look at the FriendlyID gem for Rails, I think it can help you with slugs implementation

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using FriendlyID gem for Rails. It made the slug implementation really easy.

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a slug attribute to your model and generate a slug based on your interest (Using SecureRandom or a string).
Write a before_action(before_create) to add slug to the record.

Add slug param to routes to access the post through it's corresponding slug like below.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :posts, param: :slug
end
```

When calling API send Post id in params to find post with id like below.

```
axios.get(`/api/posts/${params.slug}`, { params: {id: `${params.postId}`})
```

Follow the below link for further information.

https://hackernoon.com/using-custom-slugs-for-rails-urls-500eb3f58f3c?gi=ec1178bf28d